Outcome vs. elementary event, which of them is assigned a probability?
A previous question here asked about the difference between "outcomes" and "elementary events". The answer was that

An event is some subset of the sample space. One possible event is the set containing only one outcome. Events containing only one outcome are called elementary events.

This is clear enough. Nonetheless, I'm having a hard time deciding which of the terms would apply in a context such as the following:

When there is more than one outcome/elementary event that satisfies a condition (for instance, $P(x_i>3)$ in one dice roll), we can add the individual probabilities.

Or:

When we have a complex sample space $S$, and as long as we assume that the outcomes/elementary events of each experiment are independent of each other (by symmetry), then the probability of each result in $S$ is the product of the probability of each outcome/elementary event in $ S_1$ and $S_2$.


The standard setting in probability theory is a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, with a set $\Omega$, a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and a probability measure $P$. The outcomes are the elements $\omega \in \Omega$ and they are also called 'elementary events'.
The probability measure $P$ is a mapping from $\mathcal{A}$ to $[0, 1]$ ($P: \mathcal{A} \to [0, 1]$), so it assigns probabilities to (measurable) sub-sets of $\Omega$, the events. Since the outcomes $\omega$ are elements and not subsets of $\Omega$ they are not assigned a probability.
If $\Omega$ is finite or countable, then $\mathcal{A}$ is often selected such that it contains all single-element sets $\{ \omega \}$ and they are also sometimes referred to as 'elementary events'. Hence, if we use this broader terminology, then a probability is also assigned to elementary events.
